# If the capacity of a slice has been modified by the unsafe.Pointer, can the rest memory reused by the garbage collection?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Think about this case:

```
s := make([]byte, 512, 1024)
(*reflect.SliceHeader)((unsafe.Pointer(&s))).Cap = 512
```

are the last 512 bytes memory can be collected by the GC?

Whether it is or not, Why?

Comment: You don't need to use an `unsafe.Pointer` to change the capacity of a slice. You can simply use a re-slicing expression like `s[:512:512]`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the current garbage collector will not collect partial slices or strings. The same is true for:

```
s=s[:512:512] // Like your example but idiomatically starting in Go1.3
s=s[128:] // first 128 elements are not collected.
```